# install mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, windows, installation

If I have an application that uses a mysql Server to keep its back end database is there a way to bundle the mysql installation with the application installer?

The installer must search if there is an existing mysql server and configure it to work with the application or install mysql and configure it. The target platform is windows.

Comment: You really should consider using a more embeddable database like Derby or SQLite. What is your application installer?

Comment: Ignoring the bad idea part of this question, MySQL is under the GPL which means if you're going to redistribute it along with your application you must follow the GPL rules and also *your* application must be licensed under the GPL. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225987/can-someone-explain-mysqls-license-and-what-it-means-to-closed-source-developme - that said, even open source GPL licensed applications rarely do this

Answer (score -1):

You can't distribute mysql database according to MySQL license agreement typically:

" MySQL software for your personal applications as long as you do not distribute them"

http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing//commercial-license.html

However, if your application is open source and you have some of kind agreement in terms of distributing the MySql then you can download and package a set of generic binary files on the below link which will allow you to have it available as part of your install package.

[MySql Binary package](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-installation.html)

Comment: That is the *commercial* license. Regular old MySQL is under the GPL; of course you can redistribute it. If you distribute it with your application then your application also must be GPL licensed, however.

Comment: ok I added some more information for you in the above answer based on the feedback you provided. I hope this helps.